Pine Script MartinGale-Strategy Issues
This is a representation of the Martingale strategy in Pine Script code.
I'm trying to backtest this strategy on TradingView, but the function that doubles the bet amount isn't working correctly.
The logic of the strategy is simple:

Repeat the trade sequence under.
Set the TP (Take Profit) and SL (Stop Loss) at predefined percentages.
If the TP is hit and you win, enter a position in the same direction as before with the base amount. Conversely, if the SL is hit and you lose, enter a position in the opposite direction with an amount that's double the previous one.

For example, if I first enter a long position with $100 and lose, I would enter a short position with $200, and if I lose again, I would enter a long position with $400. After a win, I should then enter a long position with $100 again.
What should I do to make the code work correctly?
The variable martin currently stores the number of consecutive losses.
I need help.
//@version=5
strategy("Martin_Ver05", overlay=true, initial_capital=15000)


var int start_date = timestamp(2024, 7, 1, 0, 0)
var int end_date = timestamp(2024, 7, 15, 23, 59)


var string[] trade_sequence = array.new_string(12, "")
array.set(trade_sequence, 0, "long")
array.set(trade_sequence, 1, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 2, "long")
array.set(trade_sequence, 3, "long")
array.set(trade_sequence, 4, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 5, "long")
array.set(trade_sequence, 6, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 7, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 8, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 9, "long")
array.set(trade_sequence, 10, "short")
array.set(trade_sequence, 11, "long")



var int trade_index = 0
var int leverage = 50
var int martin = 0
var int initial_qty = 200


current_trade = array.get(trade_sequence, trade_index)


tp_percent = 26
sl_percent = 16


float long_tp = na
float long_sl = na
float short_tp = na
float short_sl = na


if strategy.position_size > 0
    long_tp := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_percent / (100* leverage))
    long_sl := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_percent / (100* leverage))

if strategy.position_size < 0
    short_tp := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp_percent / (100* leverage))
    short_sl := strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + sl_percent / (100* leverage))



if (time >= start_date and time <= end_date)
    if strategy.opentrades == 0
        if current_trade == "long"
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty= initial_qty * math.pow(2, martin) )

        else if current_trade == "short"
            strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty= initial_qty * math.pow(2, martin) )
        
        trade_index := (trade_index + 1) % array.size(trade_sequence)



    if strategy.position_size > 0
        if high >= long_tp
            strategy.close("Long")
            martin := 0
        else if low <= long_sl
            strategy.close("Long")
            martin := martin + 1

    if strategy.position_size < 0
        if low <= short_tp
            strategy.close("Short")
            martin := 0
        else if high >= short_sl
            strategy.close("Short")
            martin := martin + 1

I simply wanted to implement a Martingale strategy where the entry amount doubles when the SL is hit and reset to the initial value when the TP is hit.

Let me know what i can do. I appreciate all-somebody answers me. Thanks!
